# split a line of text into two lines using a <br> in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code (inherited!) that will split a line of text into 2 lines with a html line break `<br/>`.

```
public static string BreakLineIntoTwo(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return string.Empty;
    if (input.Length < 12) return input;

    int pos = input.Length / 2;

    while ((pos < input.Length) && (input[pos] != ' '))
        pos++;

    if (pos >= input.Length) return input;

    return input.Substring(0, pos) + "<br/>" + input.Substring(pos + 1);
}
```

The rules seem to be if the line of text is less than 12 characters then just return it. If not find the middle of the text and move along to the next space and insert a line break. We can also assume that there are no double spaces and no additional spaces at the end and the the text is not just one long line of letters `abcdefghijkilmnopqrstuvwxyz` etc.

This seems to work fine and my question is `Is there a more elegant approach to this problem?`

Comment: Anything wrong with `string.Replace("\n", "<br />")`?

Comment: @Mehrdad - I don't have \n in my text to replace.

Comment: I presume you're trying to achieve this on html side.What if you put text into a container which has a word-wrap css property that does exactly the same thing when length of text is less than containers ?

Comment: @Myra - I am open to this, care to share a link showing an example?

Comment: I don't know where you want to use this method. If it's only function is match text to display area then it would be better to use CSS.

Comment: @Rippo - Obviously, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @zgorawski - I have found this error whilst testing and have added to original code.

Comment: @Rippo I added an answer to this question including example,please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible improvement would be something along the lines of

```
private const MinimumLengthForBreak = 12;
private const LineBreakString = "<br />";

public static string BreakLineIntoTwo(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return string.Empty;
    if (input.Length < MinimumLengthForBreak ) return input;

    int pos = input.IndexOf(' ', input.Length / 2);
    if (pos < 0) return input; // No space found, not checked in original code

    return input.Substring(0, pos) + LineBreakString + input.Substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Note: Syntax not checked since i'm at work and can't check atm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IndexOf` instead of looping through the string yourself.

```
public static string BreakLineIntoTwo(this HtmlHelper helper, string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return string.Empty;
    if (input.Length < 12) return input;

    int pos = input.Length / 2;

    pos = input.IndexOf(' ', pos);

    return input.Substring(0, pos) + "<br/>" + input.Substring(pos + 1);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check if the IndexOf couldn't find the character, so it doesn't do the same as the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use css property of **word-wrap**.

With word-wrap property,you can force long text to wrap in a new line by specifying break-word.

Check this [example](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/word-wrap-force-text-to-wrap/)

Best Regards

Myra

Comment: Not sure if this is compatible with IE7 and IE8

Comment: It's compatible on both versions.Check msdn document here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

a shorter version of what you had using 'IndexOf' and 'Insert':

```
    private string BreakLineIntoTwo(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return string.Empty;
        if (input.Length < 12) return input;          

       int index = input.IndexOf(" ", input.Length/2);

       return index > 0 ? input.Insert(index, "<br />") : input;
    }
```

I did this as a separate method but you should be able to easily change this into your extension method.